# Analytic function

Tags: sql

I am looking an efficient way to achieve 'Item_type' which is taking the sum of distinct product by partitioning 'Type'.

```
Product no. Item    Type    Item_type
Product A   11  Type 1  24
Product B   5   Type 1  24
Product B   5   Type 1  24
Product C   8   Type 1  24
Product C   8   Type 1  24
Product A   11  Type 2  20
Product D   9   Type 2  20
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want `sum(distinct)`.  I think that is not sensible; it usually illustrates an issue with how the data is produced.

It is better to identify one specific row for the sum, which we can do using `row_number()`:

```
select . . .,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then item_no else 0 end) as item_type
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by product, type order by product) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```